# Creating DataType for linked List c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

I am trying to create a Linked List where the data in the node is a custom DataType of type `Car` that holds the arrival time and departure time of cars in a garage. when i run the code i keep getting

> lnk2019 error: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Car::Car(void)" (??0Car@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall CarNode::CarNode(void)" (??0CarNode@@QAE@XZ).

here is code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Car
{
public:
    Car();

    int getArrival()
    {
        return arrival;
    };

    int getDeparture()
    {
        return departure;
    };

    int arrival = 0;
    int departure = 0;
};

class CarNode
{
public:
    Car data;
    CarNode* next;
};

class CarLinkedList
{
public:

    CarLinkedList(Car &e)  
    {
        cout << "Constructor for Car:  " << e.getArrival() << endl;
        head = new CarNode; 
        head->data = e;
        head->next = NULL;
    }

    void addFront(Car& e)       
    {
        CarNode *v = new CarNode;           
        v->data = e;                    
        v->next = head;                 
        head = v;                       
        cout << "addFront: new head is " << head->data.getArrival() << endl;
    } 
private:
    CarNode *head;              // pointer to the head of list

};

int main()
{
    Car chevy;

    CarLinkedList *s;
    s = new CarLinkedList(chevy);
    s->printSLL();

    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: You declare that `Car` has a constructor `Car()`, but there is no body for it. Hence the link error.

Comment: Also, if you are going to make `arrival` and `departure` public, get rid of the accessor functions (and really, not usually done in C++ anyway).

Comment: would it be beter to have CarNode as a struct instead of a class?

Answer (score 0):

You have this in your code:

```
class Car {
    public:
        Car();
```

But I don't see the definition of it anywhere:

```
Car::Car() {
    ...
}
```